# SendInput для Alt + NumPad*

Tags: c#, winapi

Здравствуйте. Хотел попросить помощи в следующем вопросе: как эмулировать ввод Alt + NumPad* ?

У меня есть XML-файл с инструкциями, аля:

```
<Action Name="KeyDown" Key="ALT">
<Action Name="KeyDown" Key="NUMPAD1">
<Action Name="KeyUp" Key="NUMPAD1">
<Action Name="KeyDown" Key="NUMPAD2">
<Action Name="KeyUp" Key="NUMPAD2">
<Action Name="KeyUp" Key="ALT">
```

Эти инструкции считываются и по каждому Action создаётся INPUT, который посылается WinAPI:

```
WinAPI.INPUT action = new WinAPI.INPUT();
action.Type = (UInt32)SendInputEventType.InputKeyboard;

action.Data.Keyboard = new WinAPI.KEYBDINPUT((uint)_action, (ushort)_key);

WinAPI.SendInput(1, new WinAPI.INPUT[] { action }, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(action));
```

Конструктор KEYBDINPUT:

```
public KEYBDINPUT(uint action, ushort key)
{

    Vk = key;
    Scan = 0;
    Time = 0;
    Flags = action;
    ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

}
```

Комбинации клавиш : Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V, работают, а Alt + NUMPAD - ничего не вводит.

Пробовал через Scan, c помощью скан кода и флага KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE. Получилось ровно тоже самое.

Пытался запоминать целую комбинацию и отправлять её как список, но у меня вообще перестало что-либо выводить. Не думаю, что проблема в этом, ведь остальные комбинации работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После многократных попыток с SendMessage и PostMessage. Вернулся к SendInput и у меня получилось, всё-таки через Scan Code.

Изменил конструктор KEYBDINPUT так, что при нажатии Alt, идёт заполнение Scan и Flag:

```
if (action == (uint)Test.KeyActionType.KeyDown)
    Flags = (uint)Test.KeyActionType.ScanCode;
else
    Flags = (uint)Test.KeyActionType.ScanCode | (uint)Test.KeyActionType.KeyUp;
Scan = (ushort)MapVirtualKey(key, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать

```
SendKeys.Send("%{MULTY}");
```

Comment: Имеете ввиду {MULTIPLY}?

Comment: Да, конечно. Сорри, заторопился, не дописал )